Authenticating 2 clients of same realm of keycloak
I am having issues while authenticating 2 clients of same realm of keycloak  within a project. I have a scenario where for a particular route there should be a longer token life span to avoid frequent logout. To manage such requirement I decided to have a separate client that would have a different session and token life spans. But every time i try to authenticate my second client after already being authenticated in my first client i gets logged out and gets a new login request page to login again. Before integrating such changes direct into my project. I also configured and tested this into a local project there I was able to authenticate 2 clients of same realm and there i didnt face any such issues.
I expect that I dont get logged out. Just like my local project where i tested everything with my local keycloak.
